# Unable to insert json data into hibernate jpa

Tags: hibernate

I have just started working with angular 8. I'm trying to insert data from json into the data base table but my values are not getting properly bind. Eg if I assign value of keyId as '101' in my json then my keyId value is getting assigned to some other other column for instance keyNumber. Is there any proper way to bind your json key and column in db?

Below is my json

key:this. key Id.

keyCount this.register Form. getkeyCount). value,

key Set this.registerForm. get('keySet ).value,

V/BranchkeyPurpose: this register format
key Purpose' value.

branchKeyPurpose: static BranchKey

keysAt Branch this.registerForm. get
ike yCount Branch)value,

key Number 1. this register Form.get
key Number 1 ).value,

keyNumber2 this register Form. get(
key Number?').value.

keyNumber1A: this.register Form. get
key Number 1" ).value,

setup: this.register Form.getset lOCust ).value,

set 1 B this. register Form. get'set1BCust)value

set 2P: this.register Form.get('set2PCust).value.

set 2B: this.register Form.get('set 2 BCust).value.

set 1AP: this.register Form get set 1APCust').value.

set1AB: this.register Form.get('set1ABCust").value

Link for Java code. I'm unable to upload image here. Kindly excuse me.

https://code.sololearn.com/c0tUh4WSeV3q/?ref=app

Comment: Mention what you have tried so far

Comment: Please provide any relevant code to determinate what is going on.